# Angular Convention for declaring controllers

Tags: angularjs

Is there an established convention regarding declaration of controllers? (Or any form of module-level configuration).

I have observed two different approaches in use:

```
var shoppingCartModule = angular.module('ShoppingCart',[])
shoppingCartModule.controller('CheckoutCtrl', function($scope) { ... });
```

vs

```
angular.module('ShoppingCart').controller('CheckoutCtrl', function($scope) { ... });
```

Are there any benefits between the two approaches?  Also, is there a preferred (or emerging) convention?

I'm specifically interested in benefits for non-trivial apps with many modules, where declarations of controllers and modules may span many files.

Comment: I just want to mention the second method you gave is typically used in jfiddles for examples and Terry's answer much more oriented for a real app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally I do the following (reasons after):

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', ['$dependency', 'anotherDependency',      
  function($dependency, anotherDependency) {
    ...
  }
]);
```

Reasons:

- I try and avoid the global scope
- Redundantly declaring dependencies with string equivalents allows you to safely minify your code
- It's consistent, clean and the whole story is there.  Eg. with `app.something` you don't know what `app` is, with `angular.module('myApp').something' it's pretty obvious what that is.

***Edit***: Just remembered a cool video I saw on this very topic a while ago - http://www.egghead.io/video/tTihyXaz4Bo.  If you haven't checked out John's site, I highly recommend it.  I was so impressed with his videos I donated, and you should too!

Comment: I use this method as well.

Comment: this looks good but why are you declaring angular.module at the top first?

Comment: @bsiddiqui I believe to inject dependencies such as `angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953938/declaring-controllers-in-angularjs    agrees with @Terry 's answer

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I find it be a little bit cleaner this way:

```
angular.
  module('myApp').
  controller('myController', ['$dependency', 'anotherDependency', myAppController]);

function myAppController($dependency, anotherDependency) {
  ...
}
```

Or, even more better:

```
var Controllers  = {};

Controllers .someController = function myAppController($dependency, anotherDependency) {
  ...
}

angular.
  module('myApp').
  controller('myController', ['$dependency', 'anotherDependency', Controllers .someController]);
```

Comment: Your first example is far cleaner than any other in this question or elsewhere