# Declaring controllers in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, function, angularjs

I've seen that on AngularJS tutorials, that some people declare their controller functions like so:

```
function FirstController($scrope) {
    // do something with $scope
}
```

and other have done it like this:

```
var FirstController = function ($scope) {
    // do something with scope
}
```

Which way is the best way to declare a controller in your JS file, that will work best with the latest version of AngularJS ( right now 1.0.7 ), as in what are the best practices? Or does it not really matter?

Comment: either way works fine for best practice, look below for @ssorallen answer

Comment: Same answer (with a tiny bit fore explanation) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035890/angular-convention-for-declaring-controllers

Comment: Answer I gave on a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27383257/1254597

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should follow the second example they offer, which uses a string to identify your controller rather than a potentially global function. Use the Array syntax so you can minify your code without worrying about the minifier renaming function parameters.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.controller('GreetingCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

Source: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: exactly, this is clearly explained in the official angularjs docs.

Comment: To be fair, the first example in the Angular docs shows exactly what the original poster typed. The Angular team should remove that example since it is bad practice.

Comment: To be honest, this really does look confusing unless you read through the angularJS docs, and understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

```js
myApp.controller('myControl',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.controlname = "Something";
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of declaring Controllers is using the array notation:

```
 someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'dep1', 'dep2', function($scope,  dep1, dep2) {
     ...
     $scope.aMethod = function() {
     ...
    }
  ... 
}]);
```

according to angularJS site : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di