# $http is not a function error in ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-grid, ag-grid

I am using Angular Grid (ag-grid) to display data. In my table, whenever user adds a comment by inline editing, i intend to make a rest call and save comment in DB. I have put `$http` thing to make rest call in `newValueHandler`. In debugger i see that `newValueHandler` is invokded but `$http` is undefined. And then i get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: $http is not a function`

```
function CompletedActionsCtrl($scope, $http) {
    var columnDefs = [{
        headerName: "Comments",
        field: "comments",
        width: 180,
        filter: 'text',
        editable: true,
        newValueHandler:addCommentHandler,
        valueGetter: function (params) {
            if (params.data.comments != null) {
                return params.data.comments[0];
            }
        }
    }]


function addCommentHandler(params,$http){
    var url = "./postComment";
    $http({method: 'GET',url: url
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {}, function errorCallback(response) {});}


//==Controller invoker==
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'agGrid']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/completed_actions', {
        templateUrl: 'completed_actions_partial.html',
        controller: CompletedActionsCtrl
    });
}]);
```

Seems to be a trivial task, and i am sure i am missing something basic.

P.S. New to Javascript and angularjs.

== Code Flow Explanation ==
When user hits completed actions tab, `CompletedActionsCtrl` is invoked by routing. Inside this controller, a grid is prepared and rendered. Now when user edits the comment, and submits it, `newValueHandler` is invoked which is `function addCommentHandler`

== Update == 
Got it working by instead of calling a private function as handler, defined an anonymous function.

So removed this ->

```
newValueHandler:addCommentHandler,
```

And Added this ->

```
newValueHandler:function(params){
                var url = "./postComment";
                $http({method: 'GET',url: url})
                    .then(function successCallback(response) {},
                        function errorCallback(response) {});},
```

But the problem is that i need to have this handler at many places, and this approach will cause lot of code duplication. Any better ideas?

Comment: Where is the controller code, from where you call that function?

Comment: did you tried this to pass those as the parameters? `controller: ["$scope", "$http", CompletedActionsCtrl($scope, $http)]`

Comment: yes. it doesn't work.

Comment: follow this link might be helpful for you, it passes `apitoken` argument to another one : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#service-recipe

Answer (score 1):

Remove `$http` from your function, the parameter which you have added on your `addCommentHandler` function is vanishing the existence `$http` service.

**Code**

```
function addCommentHandler(params){ //<-- removed $http paramter function.
    var url = "./postComment";
    $http({method: 'GET',url: url
  })
  .then(function successCallback(response) {}, 
     function errorCallback(response) {});
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But i am still getting the error. `Uncaught ReferenceError: $http is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

Remove $http from method declaration, you are trying to inject a angular service to a private method!

Comment: Thanks. But i am still getting the error. `Uncaught ReferenceError: $http is not defined`

Comment: to use `$http` angularjs service you need to inject it into controller under this method is used, show me you controller code please ?

Comment: Thanks! Added it in the Qs. plz see the code under `//==Controller invoker==` and Code Flow Explanation.

Comment: I think your issue here is the way you did your controller, `CompletedActionsCtrl` have no idea what $http is, check plz this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17954031/3033318) how to declare a controller, then in [] of controller you can inject a angularjs services like $http and use them in your function.

Comment: But i am injecting `$http` in `CompletedActionsCtrl`. Also, if i use `$http` inside this controller then also it works fine. Problem is i can't use `$http` inside a private function(`addCommentHandler` in this case) called from `CompletedActionsCtrl`.

Comment: but you need to add this under `app.controller('CompletedActionsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  yourFunction(){ // here now you have $http available }
});`