# AngularJS: Different approach to declare controller with injection

Tags: angularjs

i have seen few approach to declare controller in angular.

### QS 1

```
angular.module('MyApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Hello';
    });
}
```

in the above code no where it is specified that **MyCtrl** is a part of module name **MyApp**. do we need to add controller to **MyApp module ?** or it will be added automatically to **MyApp module ?**

### QS 2

```
var app;

(function () {
    app = angular.module("TestApp", []);
})();

app.controller('TestController', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.TestAngularMethod = function () {
        alert('Hello you are calling angular js method.');
    }
}]);
```

i have seen some people use [] to inject dependency like ["$scope" but some people do not use 3rd bracket to inject dependency.

see this **["$scope"** does it carry any special meaning ?

because in function we always specify dependency name like this way **function ($scope)**

so tell me when **3rd bracket** we need to use to inject dependency?

or is it any `syntactic sugar or personal preference` ?

code taken from http://dotnet-concept.com/Tips/2015/6/5798829/How-to-call-angularJS-function-from-javascript-jquery

learning angular. so encounter various different code and that is why trying to understand. help would be appreciated. thanks

### EDIT

i saw this post on the same topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/17954031/508127

they are saying if we declare controller like below one and if we minify then problem may occur but do not discuss why problem will occur.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Hello';
    });
}
```

anyone can shade some light on it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Q1 you should do something like this:

```
var app=angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller("MyBaseCtrl", [MyCtrl]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Hello';
 });
```

}

or

```
angular.module('Mypp', []);

angular.module('MyApp').controller('MyCtrl', function (){
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Hello';

});
```

As for Q2, there is an ending bracket:

```
app.controller('TestController', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
$scope.TestAngularMethod = function () {
    alert('Hello you are calling angular js method.');
}
}**]**);
```

I wrapped it in ** and ** to emphasize

Comment: Q2 when follow this approach where we need to use 3rd bracket?

Comment: 3-rd bracket?? There is an opening bracket and a closing bracket. Where do you get a 3rd one?

Comment: i am saying when we need to pass dependencies name in array like this way `["$scope"]` ? because i have this is not mandatory but when and why we should follow this pattern? share it if u know.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking when to pass in $scope variable?

Comment: i said i can write below way where no this bracket [] exist
`app.controller('TestController', function ($scope) {
$scope.TestAngularMethod = function () {
    alert('Hello you are calling angular js method.');
}
});`
so when why should i work with [] when declare controller ?

Answer (score 3):

See this detailed style guide that explains best practices and different patterns. It will clear out the confusions.

See this dependency inject section, which is relevant to your question

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#manual-annotating-for-dependency-injection

Answer (score 1):

QS1 : Yes, you need to subscribe the controller like this,

```
app.controller('SomeName', MyCtrl);
```

QS2: On minifying(Minification Engine reduces variable names to short hand notation but does not change strings), the minification engine reduces variable name to a short name. For example, `$scope` will be shortened to `s` etc. If you keep $scope in ["$scope", as $scope is now placed inside `""` which make it as a string instead of a variable name and hence is not converted to short name like above and angular knows what "s" means when file is minified.

Answer (score 1):

I always recommend [John Papa Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controllers). It says that you should use the `controller as` syntax:

```
<div ng-controller="UserController as userVm">
    {{userVm.***}}
</div>
```

and declare it as:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('UserController', userController);

userController.$inject = [**DEPENDENCIES**];
function userController(**DEPENDENCIES**){
    var vm = this;
}
```

Note that it is using a ViewModel pattern. You should really read the guide.

The `userController.$inject = [**DEPENDENCIES**]` is similar to the `['**DEPENDENCIES**'...` syntax, and it is used to prevent error after minification (as stated by Aman).